# java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called in listAdapter

Tags: listview, onclick

I am trying to setup `onClick` in the `ListView` which is getting news from database. when I select 1st list item, it opens but on second item my app. crashes.

Here is the code for it.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Utility.logCatMsg("Adapter GetView Function");
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        // Utility.logCatMsg("Making Holder");
        holder.Maintext = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        holder.img = (SmartImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_image);
        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);

        if (data.size() <= 0) {
            holder.Maintext.setText("No Data");
        } else {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues = null;
            tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);
            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
            holder.Maintext.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
            holder.img.setImageUrl(tempValues.getImage(), R.drawable.ic_action_articles);
            holder.img.setTag(tempValues);
            holder.Maintext.setTag(tempValues);
            /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/
            //       vi.setOnClickListener(new UserMyListingAdapter.OnItemClickListener(position));
            final SmartImageView img = (SmartImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title_image);
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedValues = (ListModel) img.getTag();
                    getNews();
                }
            });

            final TextView text1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
            text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedValues = (ListModel) text1.getTag();
                    getNews();
                }
            });
        }
        return vi;
    }

    private void getNews() {
        tempValues = selectedValues;
        Bundle argument = new Bundle();
        String imgg, titlee, newss;
        imgg = tempValues.getImage();
        titlee = tempValues.getCompanyName();
        newss = tempValues.getDesc();
        argument.putString("img", imgg);
        argument.putString("title", titlee);
        argument.putString("news", newss);
        NewsLayout frag = new NewsLayout();
        frag.setArguments(argument);
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, frag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        //transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: im sorry code is not properly formatted.. :\